# Why a+=1 is a thread-safe operation in ruby?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, thread-safety

Code Snippet:

```
a = 0
Array.new(50){
  Thread.new {
    500_000.times { a += 1 }
  }
}.each(&:join)
p "a: #{a}"
```

Result: `a = 25_000_000`.

In my understanding, (MRI) Ruby use GIL, so there is only one ruby thread can get the CPU, but when thread-switch happend, some data of ruby thread will be stored for restoring thread later. So, in theory, `a += 1` may not be thread-safe.

But the result above turns out I'm wrong. Does Ruby makes `a+=1` atomic? If true, which operations can be considered thread-safe?

Answer (score 5):

### It's Neither Atomic Nor Thread-Safe

In your example, the apparent consistency is largely due to the global interpreter lock, but is also partly due to the way your Ruby engine and your code sequences (theoretically) asynchronous threads. You are getting consistent results because each loop in each thread is simply incrementing the current value of *a*, which is *not* a block-local or thread-local variable. With threads on the YARV virtual machine, only one thread at a time is inspecting or setting the current value of *a*, but I wouldn't really say that it's an atomic operation. It's just a byproduct of the engine’s lack of real-time concurrency between threads, and the underlying implementation of the Ruby virtual machine.

If you're concerned about preserving thread-safety in Ruby without relying on idiosyncratic behaviors that just happen to appear consistent, consider using a thread-safe library like [concurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby). Otherwise, you may be relying on behaviors that aren't guaranteed across Ruby engines or Ruby versions.

For example, three consecutive runs of your code in JRuby (which *does* have concurrent threads) will generally yield different results on each run. For example:

1. `#=> "a: 3353241"`
2. `#=> "a: 3088145"`
3. `#=> "a: 2642263"`

Comment: "With green threads […]" – Note that no currently existing Ruby implementation uses green threads. (Unless, say, you run TruffleRuby or JRuby on a JVM or IronRuby on a CLI VES that uses green threads, although I don't think one exists currently.) The last one to use green threads was MRI, which has not been maintained by its developers since 2013, and was dropped even from the last Long-Term-Support release of any Linux distribution in 2017. YARV, MRuby, TruffleRuby, JRuby, IronRuby, MagLev all use native OS threads. Opal doesn't have threads at all.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I got some useful infomation from CRuby source code about multithread, which helps me understand the confusion: https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/master/vm_eval.c#L110.

Answer (score 4):

Ruby doesn't have a well-defined Memory Model, so in some philosophical sense, the question is non-sensical, since without a Memory Model, the term "thread-safe" isn't even defined. For example, the [ISO Ruby Language Specification](https://iso.org/standard/59579.html) doesn't even document the [`Thread` class](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Thread.html).

The way that people write concurrent code in Ruby without a well-defined Memory Model is essentially "guess-and-test". You guess what the implementations will do, then you test as many versions of as many implementations on as many platforms and as many operating systems on as many CPU architectures and as many different system sizes as possible.

As you can see in [Todd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62237345/2988), even just testing *one* other implementation already reveals that your conclusion was wrong. (Pro tip: *never* make a generalization based on a sample size of 1!)

The alternative is to use a library that has already done the above, such as the [`concurrent-ruby`](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby) library mentioned in Todd's answer. They do all the testing I mentioned above. They also work closely with the maintainers of the various implementations. E.g. Chris Seaton, the lead developer of TruffleRuby is also one of the maintainers of `concurrent-ruby`, and Charlie Nutter, the lead developer of JRuby, is one of the contributors.

Answer (score 2):

> But the result above turns out I'm wrong.

The results are misleading. In Ruby, `a += 1` is a shorthand for:

```
a = a + 1
```

With `a + 1` being a *method call* that occurs before the assignment. Since integers are objects in Ruby, we can override that method:

```
module ThreadTest
  def +(other)
    super
  end
end
Integer.prepend(ThreadTest)
```

The above code doesn't do anything useful, it just calls `super`. But merely adding a Ruby implementation on top of the built-in C implementation is enough to break (or fix) your test:

```
Integer.prepend(ThreadTest)

a = 0
Array.new(50){
  Thread.new {
    500_000.times { a += 1 }
  }
}.each(&:join)
p "a: #{a}"
#=> "a: 11916339"
```

Comment: thanks a lot, great example. So can I say C functions are thread-safe and Ruby methods are unsafe?

Comment: Well, yes and no. Ruby (MRI/YARV) doesn't switch threads while executing a C method, so that explains "why" your code behaves that way. But within your code, you can't tell a C method from a Ruby method. Relying on an implementation detail of a specific interpreter would be very risky. Furthermore, `a += 1` are _two_ operations: `a + 1` and `a = ...` – a thread switch could still occur _between_ them (again: implementation specific). If you want to have thread-safe code, you have to use a [mutex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Mutex.html).